# How to export data from redshift to s3 using airflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, airflow

I am running a query that selects the data from redshift and inserts into s3 bucket. The redshift connection are correct because I print the print(hook.get_records(sql_one)) and is working but when I am running the airflow[dag] using the UNLOAD, it gets stuck. Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

```
redshift = PostgresHook('redshift_creds')
S3Hook for credentials
sql_one = """
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10);
    """
query = """
            UNLOAD ('{select_query}')
            TO 's3://{s3_bucket}/{s3_key}'
            CREDENTIALS
            'aws_access_key_id={access_key};aws_secret_access_key=   {secret_key}'
            REGION AS 'region_type'
            DELIMITER AS ',';
            """.format(select_query=sql_one,
                        s3_bucket='bucket_name',
                        s3_key='redshift_data.csv',
                        access_key=credentials.access_key,
                        secret_key=credentials.secret_key)

redshift.run(query)
```

Comment: To me your `SQL` query seems syntactically incorrect, if its not typo. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10);`

Comment: as @RedBoy points out the query seems off. Everything else looks fine. Have you tried running this unload command directly on redshift ? What happens ?

Comment: @RedBoy that SQL is syntactically correct. The LIMIT clause needs to be used inside a subquery in an unload statement.

Comment: @Michael can you elaborate on what happens when this is run in Airflow, "it gets stuck" isn't much to go on. Do you have any log output from Airflow or Redshift?

Comment: @Nathan the output from airflow logs is :successful connected to redshift and it's starting to execute the UNLOAD query, when is executing the UNLOAD query its printing it and it's running without displaying or showing any errors. I left it running for 30min and is not inserting any records at all. Do you think the problem is with redshift?

Comment: Do you see the unload statement in the Redshift query log? e.g.
select * from stl_query 
where lower(querytxt) like '%unload%'
order by starttime desc 
limit 10;

Comment: Note if you're not a superuser then you will only see your own queries in stl_query so make sure you're either a superuser or connected as the Airflow user.